# angular - factory error 'service not defined'

Tags: angularjs

Getting into Angular. I'm trying to set up a factory to store animation functions.  Only thing I get is 'service is not defined' in the console.  Here's a codepen link: http://codepen.io/tplummerptc/pen/dGbKOp

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.factory('soarimation', function(){
  service.soarFlash = function(target, color) {
    target = (target == undefined) ? false : target;
    color = (color != 'default') ? 'defualt' : color;

    // Set animation color
    if(color != 'default') {
      var aniClass = 'flash-'+color;
    } else {
      var aniClass = 'flash';
    }
    if(!target) {
      $(this)
        .closest(target)
        .addClass(aniClass)
        .delay(1000)
        .queue(function(next){
        $(this).removeClass(aniClass);
        next();
      });
    } else {
      $(this)
        .addClass(aniClass)
        .delay(1000)
        .queue(function(next){
        $(this).removeClass(aniClass);
        next();
      });
    }
  }
});
app.controller('addRow',function($scope, soarimation){
  $scope.submitRow = function(event){
    angular.element(event.currentTarget).soarFlash('li');
  }
});
```

Comment: You haven't defined `service` in `service.soarFlash = ...`. Also, your factory function doesn't return anything. I also don't see how the `soarFlash` method would be added to `angular.element`

Comment: You are trying to add soarFlash to a thing called service, but never declared service. Is it a module? If yes, either create one or get using the getter on module... var service = angular.module('services');

Comment: What I'm trying to do is add the `.soarFlash` function to be called from the factory `soarmation`.  Is that not what a factory is for?  I was under the impression setting `service.soarFlash` was registering the function to the `soarmation` factory, where I can then call that function in a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factories in angularjs always return a object. You have to declare the service object inside `app.factory` method and then add the desired functions and variables to it. Finally return that object. You can use this object in your controller by using the factory name.

```
app.factory('soarimation', function(){

  var service = {}; //Declaring the object
  service.soarFlash = function(target, color) {
    target = (target == undefined) ? false : target;
    color = (color != 'default') ? 'defualt' : color;

    // Set animation color
    if(color != 'default') {
      var aniClass = 'flash-'+color;
    } else {
      var aniClass = 'flash';
    }
    if(!target) {
      $(this)
        .closest(target)
        .addClass(aniClass)
        .delay(1000)
        .queue(function(next){
        $(this).removeClass(aniClass);
        next();
      });
    } else {
      $(this)
        .addClass(aniClass)
        .delay(1000)
        .queue(function(next){
        $(this).removeClass(aniClass);
        next();
      });
    }
  }

  return service;  // Return the object
});

app.controller('addRow',function($scope, soarimation){
  $scope.submitRow = function(event){
    var elem = angular.element(event.currentTarget);
    soarimation.soarFlash(elem);
  }
});
```